# How to choose between different AWS IoT Rule engine for taking action for incoming message to mqtt topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

We are using AWS iot core as mqtt broker to receive and publish the data from device and other webservice respectively.
Our webservice which is acting as a subscriber here is built on top of java/spring-boot.
So basically device will be sending message over a single mqtt service and the webservice will be consuming the message from this topic.

But as to build scalable design, we dont want our webservice to directly consume the message from the topic.

We are expecting around 10000 devices to publish the messages concurrently to the single topic. We also dont want to use shared subscription due to some restriction and limitation.

We want to configure IOT rule engine. Below are the few approaches we thought as of now:

1. IOT rule via http post: Webservice will expose one Rest API that will be responsible for processing the messages(aynchronously)
2. IOT rule via sqs: Webservice will have sqs listner that will poll the data from sqs.
3. IOT rule via dynamoDB: Cron job will be fetching messages from the dynamoDB and do the processing.

There are other iot rule actions also that can be taken but I wanted to know what would be the best practice and what all factor we should consider in order choose IOT rule action.

Does all these IOT rule will have same cost implication or does it vary on the actions/resources(sqs, dynamoDB etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to go with SQS since it is serverless and it will scale automatically. You can then, as you mentioned, consume the messages from the queue at your own pace (please note that you can also connect an AWS Lambda to SQS and run your custom logic in lambda with java runtime).

To reduce pricing even further on your solution, I'd highly recommend to use [basic ingest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-basic-ingest.html). Basic ingest is a specific feature in AWS IoT core that bypasses the MQTT broker by publishing the message directly to AWS IoT rule. Since you are not subscribing to the topic, using this feature makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. One thing I need more details on auto-scale. How does SQS support auto-scale. And also if we can compare SQS to Kafka(MSK), then which one would be more appropriate to use.